# Can send but not receive BLE messages on android

Tags: java, android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am building an app where I need BLE devices to connect with each other and send messages. My problem is when my android device connects to an iOS device, only the iOS devices receives the message that android is advertising. Android never recieves the message iOS is sending. After debugging and testing, I am certain this is a problem with android, not iOS because iOS devices send and receive messages between each other properly.

I am confused on what to fix with my android code in order to have it successfully receive messages from iOS.

```
public class mapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    
    private final Set<Peer> nearbyPeers = new HashSet<>();
    private static Map<String, String> times = new HashMap<>();
    private int counter = 0;

   

    private static final String TAG2 = "ClientActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final String docName = "docName";


    private boolean mConnected;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner;
    private ScanCallback mScanCallback;
    private BluetoothGatt mGatt;
    public String covtraceUUID = "A82AB3FC-1695-4F7A-40F0-FE094CC218F8";
    public static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 5000;
    private BluetoothLeAdvertiser mBluetoothLeAdvertiser;
    private BluetoothGattServer mGattServer;
    private BluetoothGatt gatt;
    private boolean mEchoInitialized;

    private List<BluetoothDevice> mDevices;
    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private boolean mInitialized;

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        


        mLogHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        @SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
        String deviceInfo = "Device Info"
                + "\nName: " + mBluetoothAdapter.getName()
                + "\nAddress: " + mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();

        
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mDevices = new ArrayList<>();

        
        //End of ServerActivity

        startScan();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //ClientActivity
        // Check low energy support

        //ServerActivity
        // Check if bluetooth is enabled
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            // Request user to enable it
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBtIntent);
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Check low energy support
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            // Get a newer device
            System.out.println("No LE Support.");
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Check advertising
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()) {
            // Unable to run the server on this device, get a better device
            System.out.println("No Advertising Support.");
            finish();
            return;
        }

        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
        GattServerCallback gattServerCallback = new GattServerCallback();
        //try {
        if (gattServerCallback == null || this == null || mBluetoothManager == null) {
            System.out.println("unable to print gatt server");
            return;
        }
            mGattServer = mBluetoothManager.openGattServer(this, gattServerCallback);
        //}
        //catch (Exception e) {

        //}
        @SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
        String deviceInfo = "Device Info" + "\nName: " + mBluetoothAdapter.getName() + "\nAddress: " + mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();

        setupServer();
        startAdvertising();
        //startScan();


    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopAdvertising();
        stopServer();
    }

    //ServerActivity Start Advertising
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void startAdvertising() {
        if (mBluetoothLeAdvertiser == null) {
            return;
        }

        AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder().setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED)
                .setConnectable(true)
                .setTimeout(0)
                .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_LOW)
                .build();

        ParcelUuid parcelUuid = ParcelUuid.fromString(covtraceUUID);
        AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder().setIncludeDeviceName(false)
                //.addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(serviceUUID));
                .addServiceUuid(parcelUuid)
                .addServiceData( parcelUuid, "d".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8") ) )
                .build();

        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, mAdvertiseCallback);
    }

    //ServerActivity stop advertising
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void stopAdvertising() {
        if (mBluetoothLeAdvertiser != null) {
            mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertising(mAdvertiseCallback);
        }
    }


    private AdvertiseCallback mAdvertiseCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
            System.out.println("Peripheral advertising started.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
            System.out.println("Peripheral advertising failed: " + errorCode);
        }
    };

    //ServerActivity log
    public void log1(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, msg);


    }

    public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        System.out.println("Device added: " + device.getAddress());
        mHandler.post(() -> mDevices.add(device));
    }

    public void removeDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        System.out.println("Device removed: " + device.getAddress());
        mHandler.post(() -> {
            mDevices.remove(device);
        });
    }
    private static boolean uuidMatches(String uuidString, String... matches) {
        for (String match : matches) {
            if (uuidString.equalsIgnoreCase(match)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    private static boolean matchesServiceUuidString(String serviceIdString) {
        String covtraceUUID = "A82AB3FC-1695-4F7A-40F0-FE094CC218F8";

        return uuidMatches(serviceIdString, covtraceUUID);
    }
    @Nullable
    private static BluetoothGattService findService(List<BluetoothGattService> serviceList) {
        for (BluetoothGattService service : serviceList) {
            String serviceIdString = service.getUuid()
                    .toString();
            if (matchesServiceUuidString(serviceIdString)) {
                return service;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    private static boolean characteristicMatches(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, String uuidString) {
        if (characteristic == null) {
            return false;
        }
        UUID uuid = characteristic.getUuid();
        return uuidMatches(uuid.toString(), uuidString);
    }
    @Nullable
    private static BluetoothGattCharacteristic findCharacteristic(BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt, String uuidString) {
        List<BluetoothGattService> serviceList = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
        BluetoothGattService service = findService(serviceList);
        if (service == null) {
            System.out.println("our service is null!!!!!!!");
            return null;
        }

        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristicList = service.getCharacteristics();
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristicList) {
            if (characteristicMatches(characteristic, uuidString)) {
                return characteristic;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    public static byte[] bytesFromString(String string) {
        byte[] stringBytes = new byte[0];
        try {
            stringBytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to convert message string to byte array");
        }

        return stringBytes;
    }
    @Nullable
    public static BluetoothGattCharacteristic findEchoCharacteristic(BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt) {
        String covtraceUUID = "A82AB3FC-1695-4F7A-40F0-FE094CC218F8";
        return findCharacteristic(bluetoothGatt, covtraceUUID);
    }
    //ServerActivity send message
    private void sendMessage() {
        if (!mConnected || !mEchoInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = findEchoCharacteristic(mGatt);
        if (characteristic == null) {
            logError("Unable to find echo characteristic.");
            disconnectGattServer();
            return;
        }

        String message = String.valueOf(P2PKit.getMyPeerId());
        byte[] messageBytes = bytesFromString(message);
        if (messageBytes.length == 0) {
            logError("Unable to convert message to bytes");
            return;
        }

        characteristic.setValue(messageBytes);
        boolean success = mGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
        if (success) {
            log("Wrote: " + byteArrayInHexFormat(messageBytes));
        } else {
            logError("Failed to write data");
        }
    }

    //ServerActivity characteristic changed
    private class CharacteristicChanged extends BluetoothGattCallback {
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            byte[] messageBytes = characteristic.getValue();
            String messageString = null;
            try {
                messageString = new String(messageBytes, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Unable to convert message bytes to string");
            }
            Log.d(messageString, "Received message: ");
        }

        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                return;
            }
            BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString(covtraceUUID));
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(covtraceUUID));
            characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
            mInitialized = gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
        }

    }
    public static boolean requiresResponse(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        return (characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE) != BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE;
    }
    public void sendResponse(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, int status, int offset, byte[] value) {
        mHandler.post(() -> mGattServer.sendResponse(device, requestId, status, 0, null));
    }
    public static byte[] reverse(byte[] value) {
        int length = value.length;
        byte[] reversed = new byte[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            reversed[i] = value[length - (i + 1)];
        }
        return reversed;
    }
    private static String byteToHex(byte b) {
        char char1 = Character.forDigit((b & 0xF0) >> 4, 16);
        char char2 = Character.forDigit((b & 0x0F), 16);

        return String.format("0x%1$s%2$s", char1, char2);
    }
    public static String byteArrayInHexFormat(byte[] byteArray) {
        if (byteArray == null) {
            return null;
        }

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("{ ");
        for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(", ");
            }
            String hexString = byteToHex(byteArray[i]);
            stringBuilder.append(hexString);
        }
        stringBuilder.append(" }");

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    public static boolean requiresConfirmation(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        return (characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) == BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE;
    }
    private void notifyCharacteristic(byte[] value, UUID uuid) {
        mHandler.post(() -> {
            BluetoothGattService service = mGattServer.getService(UUID.fromString(covtraceUUID));
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(uuid);
            log("Notifying characteristic " + characteristic.getUuid().toString()
                    + ", new value: " + byteArrayInHexFormat(value));

            characteristic.setValue(value);
            boolean confirm = requiresConfirmation(characteristic);
            for(BluetoothDevice device : mDevices) {
                mGattServer.notifyCharacteristicChanged(device, characteristic, confirm);
            }
        });
    }
    public void notifyCharacteristicEcho(byte[] value) {
        notifyCharacteristic(value, UUID.fromString(covtraceUUID));
    }
    private void sendReverseMessage(byte[] message) {
        mHandler.post(() -> {
            // Reverse message to differentiate original message & response
            byte[] response = reverse(message);
            log("Sending: " + byteArrayInHexFormat(response));
            notifyCharacteristicEcho(response);
        });
    }
    //ServerActivity gattservercallback
    private class GattServerCallback extends BluetoothGattServerCallback {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothDevice device, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(device, status, newState);
            
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                addDevice(device);
                connectDevice(device);
                System.out.println("preparing to send msg 1");
                sendMessage();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                removeDevice(device);
            }
        }

        // The Gatt will reject Characteristic Read requests that do not have the permission set,
        // so there is no need to check inside the callback
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicReadRequest(BluetoothDevice device,
                                                int requestId,
                                                int offset,
                                                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicReadRequest(device, requestId, offset, characteristic);

            log("onCharacteristicReadRequest "
                    + characteristic.getUuid().toString());

            if (requiresResponse(characteristic)) {
                // Unknown read characteristic requiring response, send failure
                sendResponse(device, requestId, BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE, 0, null);
            }
            System.out.println("preparing to send msg 2");
            sendMessage();
            // Not one of our characteristics or has NO_RESPONSE property set
        }
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWriteRequest(BluetoothDevice device,
                                                 int requestId,
                                                 BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                                 boolean preparedWrite,
                                                 boolean responseNeeded,
                                                 int offset,
                                                 byte[] value) {
            super.onCharacteristicWriteRequest(device,
                    requestId,
                    characteristic,
                    preparedWrite,
                    responseNeeded,
                    offset,
                    value);
            if (UUID.fromString(covtraceUUID).equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                sendResponse(device, requestId, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, 0, null);
                sendReverseMessage(value);
            }
            
            System.out.println("preparing to send msg 3");
            sendMessage();
        }
    }

    //ServerActivity set up server
    private void setupServer() {
        BluetoothGattService service = new BluetoothGattService(UUID.fromString(covtraceUUID),
                BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);
        mGattServer.addService(service);
    }

    //ServerActivity stop server
    private void stopServer() {
        if (mGattServer != null) {
            mGattServer.close();
        }
    }

    public void log(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
        mLogHandler.post(() -> {
            Log.i(msg, msg + "\n");

        });
    }

    public void logError(String msg) {
        log("Error: " + msg);
    }

    //ClientActivity Scanning
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void startScan() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!hasPermissions() || mScanning) {
                return;
            }
        }

        disconnectGattServer();


        mScanResults = new HashMap<>();
        mScanCallback = new BtleScanCallback(mScanResults);

        mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

        // Note: Filtering does not work the same (or at all) on most devices. It also is unable to
        // search for a mask or anything less than a full UUID.
        // Unless the full UUID of the server is known, manual filtering may be necessary.
        // For example, when looking for a brand of device that contains a char sequence in the UUID
        ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
                .setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(covtraceUUID))
                .build();
        List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(scanFilter);

        ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
                .build();

        mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);

        mHandler = new Handler();
        //mHandler.postDelayed(this::stopScan, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        System.out.println("Started scanning.");
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private boolean hasPermissions() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            requestBluetoothEnable();
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }

    private void requestBluetoothEnable() {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        log("Requested user enables Bluetooth. Try starting the scan again.");
    }
    
    private void connectDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        log("Connecting to " + device.getAddress());
        GattClientCallback gattClientCallback = new GattClientCallback();
        mGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattClientCallback);
    }


    //ClientActivity Stop scan
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void stopScan() {
        if (mScanning && mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() && mBluetoothLeScanner != null) {
            mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            scanComplete();
        }

        mScanCallback = null;
        mScanning = false;
        mHandler = null;
        System.out.println("Stopped scanning.");
    }


    //ClientActivity scan Complete
    private void scanComplete() {
        if (mScanResults.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        for (String deviceAddress : mScanResults.keySet()) {
            BluetoothDevice device = mScanResults.get(deviceAddress);
            GattServerViewModel viewModel = new GattServerViewModel(device);


        }
    }


    //Client Activity set connected
    public void setConnected(boolean connected) {
        mConnected = connected;
    }
    public void initializeEcho() {
        mEchoInitialized = true;
    }
    //ClientActivity disconnect Gatt server
    public void disconnectGattServer() {
        System.out.println("Closing Gatt connection");
        mConnected = false;
        mEchoInitialized = false;
        if (mGatt != null) {
            mGatt.disconnect();
            mGatt.close();
        }
    }
    private static boolean matchesCharacteristicUuidString(String characteristicIdString) {
        String covtraceUUID = "A82AB3FC-1695-4F7A-40F0-FE094CC218F8";
        return uuidMatches(characteristicIdString, covtraceUUID);
    }
    private static boolean isMatchingCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if (characteristic == null) {
            return false;
        }
        UUID uuid = characteristic.getUuid();
        return matchesCharacteristicUuidString(uuid.toString());
    }
    public static List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> findCharacteristics(BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt) {
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> matchingCharacteristics = new ArrayList<>();

        List<BluetoothGattService> serviceList = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
        BluetoothGattService service = findService(serviceList);
        if (service == null) {
            System.out.println("cannot find charac");
            return matchingCharacteristics;
        }

        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristicList = service.getCharacteristics();
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristicList) {
            if (isMatchingCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
                matchingCharacteristics.add(characteristic);
            }
        }

        return matchingCharacteristics;
    }
    //Client Activity callback
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private class BtleScanCallback extends ScanCallback {

        private Map<String, BluetoothDevice> mScanResults;

        BtleScanCallback(Map<String, BluetoothDevice> scanResults) {
            mScanResults = scanResults;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            addScanResult(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult result : results) {
                addScanResult(result);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            logError("BLE Scan Failed with code " + errorCode);
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        private void addScanResult(ScanResult result) {
            BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
            String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
            mScanResults.put(deviceAddress, device);
        }
    }
    @Nullable
    public static String stringFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        String byteString = null;
        try {
            byteString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to convert message bytes to string");
        }
        return byteString;
    }
    public static boolean isEchoCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        String covtraceUUID = "A82AB3FC-1695-4F7A-40F0-FE094CC218F8";
        return characteristicMatches(characteristic, covtraceUUID );
    }
    //Gatt Client Callback
    private class GattClientCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            System.out.println("onConnectionStateChange newState: " + newState);

            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE) {
                logError("Connection Gatt failure status " + status);
                disconnectGattServer();
                return;
            } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                // handle anything not SUCCESS as failure
                logError("Connection not GATT sucess status " + status);
                disconnectGattServer();
                return;
            }

            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                System.out.println("Connected to device " + gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                mConnected = true;
                gatt.discoverServices();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                System.out.println("Disconnected from device");
                disconnectGattServer();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

            if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                log("Device service discovery unsuccessful, status " + status);
                return;
            }

            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> matchingCharacteristics = findCharacteristics(gatt);
            if (matchingCharacteristics.isEmpty()) {
                logError("Unable to find characteristics.");
                return;
            }

            log("Initializing: setting write type and enabling notification");
            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : matchingCharacteristics) {
                characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
                enableCharacteristicNotification(gatt, characteristic);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                log("Characteristic written successfully");
            } else {
                logError("Characteristic write unsuccessful, status: " + status);
                disconnectGattServer();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                log("Characteristic read successfully");
                readCharacteristic(characteristic);
            } else {
                logError("Characteristic read unsuccessful, status: " + status);
                
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            log("Characteristic changed, " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
            readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }

        private void enableCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            boolean characteristicWriteSuccess = gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            if (characteristicWriteSuccess) {
                log("Characteristic notification set successfully for " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                if (isEchoCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
                    System.out.println("enters isechocharac... ab to init");
                    initializeEcho();
                    System.out.println("preparing to send msg 4");
                    sendMessage();
                }
            } else {
                logError("Characteristic notification set failure for " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
            }
        }
        private void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            byte[] messageBytes = characteristic.getValue();
            log("Read: " + byteArrayInHexFormat(messageBytes));
            String message = stringFromBytes(messageBytes);
            if (message == null) {
                logError("Unable to convert bytes to string");
                return;
            }

            log("Received message: " + message);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }
```

Comment: if your Android device is connected to the iOS device, it's normal that it's no longer advertizing. When you make BLE gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic) from the Android app, do you see it on the iOS device ?